# cannot access file .php inside webroot in cakephp with nginx

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, ubuntu, nginx

I have VPS with this specification:

- Ubuntu
- Nginx
- Php
- MySql

So I make project with CakePHP in subfolder named *gogon*. This project can running and access perfectly. The site url can access at *example.com/gogon*

**problem**

I put responsivefilemanager ([responsivefilemanager.com](http://responsivefilemanager.com)) in webroot folder as *filemanager*, but when I want to access the PHP file in filemanager (*dialog.php*) site just render my *index.php* file like `example.com/index.php`

Structure of my folder:

-example.com 
---index.php
---gogon (cakephp project)
-----index.php
-----app
---------config
---------...
---------...
---------...
---------webroot
-------------filemanager
----------------dialog.php
-----lib
-----plugin
-----vendor

**This is my nginx config**

```
server {
    listen   80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php /index.php;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /var/www/html;
    }   


    location /gogon {
            rewrite_log on;
            error_log /usr/share/nginx/error.gogon.log error;

            if (-f $request_filename) {
                    break;
            }

            # Avoid recursivity
            if ($request_uri ~ /webroot/index.php) {
                    break;
            }

            rewrite ^/gogon$ /gogon/ permanent;
            rewrite ^/gogon/app/webroot/(.*) /gogon/app/webroot/index.php?url=$1 last;
            rewrite ^/gogon/(.*)$ /gogon/app/webroot/$1 last;

    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }
}
```

Comment: why you have changed default  directory structure of cakephp

Comment: I'm not changed directory structure. I just put cakephp project in subdirectory.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Basic-Principles-of-CakePHP/CakePHP-Folder-Structure.html